# What does asynchronous communication in FLP impossibility comprise of?

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed-system

Conditions:

(i) Is it just async networks, that is, messages might be arbitrarily delayed?

(ii) Does it also require that the processors should be running at different speeds?

(iii) Is the absence of a global clock also assumed?

I know that condition (i) is surely required. But are conditions (ii) and (iii) also a must? Would the impossibility not hold say if a synchronized clock could be assumed with timeouts?